# Makefile wildcard dependencies

Tags: c++, makefile

I want to include all .cpp and .cc files in the dependencies of a target using a wildcard.

Currently, I have to do the following:

```
all: main.cpp file1.cc file2.cc
    g++ -O3 -o all main.cpp file1.cc file2.cc -I./include -L./lib
```

The following does not seem to be working:

```
all: %.cpp %.cc
    g++ -O3 -o $@ $^ -I./include -L./lib
```

I get as error make: *** No rule to make target '%.cc', needed by 'all'.  Stop.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
targets := $(wildcard *.cpp) $(wildcard *.cc)
all: $(targets)
        g++ $(targets)
```

this works for me

Answer (score 3):

"%" represent implicit pattern rule,"*" is wildcard.

```
targets := $(wildcard *.cpp *.c)
all: $(targets)
    g++ $(targets)
```